# VSCodeのflake8とyapfが動いてくれない

Tags: python, python3, vscode

vscode上でflake8とyapfが動いてくれません。
現在はユーザーセッティングの方に設定を書いていて、ワークスペースの設定のほうに書いても動作してくれませんでした。
環境は以下のとおりです。

- Windows 10 Home 1803 17134.286

  - VSCode 1.27.2
  - Python 3.5.1
  - flake8 3.5.0
  - yapf 0.24.0

下記のコードで試してみましたが、だめでした。
設定の画像を貼りますので、ここが間違っていて、こうすると動くよというのがあれば教えていただければ幸いです。
よろしくおねがいします。

```
print('test')
```

[image: vscode_python]

---

解決しました。
pycodestyleのバージョンが新しいとflake8が追従しきれなくて依存性に問題が出るそうです。
そこで、flake8のバージョンを上げるか、pycodestyleのバージョンを下げると問題が解決します。
私の場合、flake8の更新が来ていたので、更新したところ、無事に動くようになりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **可能性1**: ファイルが Python モードで開かれていないのかもしれません。よくありそうなのは言語モードが「プレーンテキスト」になっている場合です。標準ではウィンドウ右下に表示されていますので、拡張子 `.py` のファイルとして保存するなどして言語モードを Python にしてください。

  [image: VS Code のウィンドウ右下のツールバー最右に「プレーンテキスト」と書かれています。言語モードの表示です。]
- **可能性2**: そもそも flake8 や yapf に適合したコードになっていて、何も通知が出ないのかもしれません。明らかにエラーが出る例を渡した方が分かりやすそうです。たとえばインデント幅が 4 の倍数になっていない以下のコードは flake8 が E111 "indentation is not a multiple of four" を出します。また yapf はこのコードのインデント幅を 4 にします。

  ```
  if True:
   pass
  ```
- **可能性3**: flake8 や yapf が VSCode 側から見つかっていないのかもしれません。`python.linting.flake8Path` や `python.formatting.yapfPath` をご確認ください。
- **可能性4**: flake8 3.5.0 において、flake8 が依存している pycodestyle と依存性の問題があるようです。2018 年 9 月現在 flake8 は pycodestyle >=2.4.0 と[互換していません](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/427)。これは flake8 がアップデートに追従しきれていないことが原因です。このため、新しいバージョンの pycodestyle をダウングレードする必要があります。まず、今インストールされている pycodestyle のバージョンを確認します。

  ```
  pip show pycodestyle
  ```

  pycodestyle のバージョンが新しすぎれば、一度アンインストールして再度バージョン指定してインストールします (おそらく後者を行うだけで大丈夫ですが、念の為アンインストールの手順も入れてあります)。

  ```
  pip uninstall pycodestyle
  pip install "pycodestyle<2.4.0"
  ```

Comment: 教えていただいた可能性を順に試してみたところ、コードが整形されたのでyapfは動くようになったと思います。ただ、flake8はまだ動かなくて、エラーが出ません。パスは完全なものを指定しているのですが...

Comment: @tomi さん、flake8 はコマンドライン上で実行したときは上手く動きますか？　たとえば cmd.exe で `flake8 test.py` といった感じで実行できます。

Comment: `flake8 test.py` を実行したところ、AttributeError: module 'pycodestyle' has no attribute 'break_around_binary_operator'というエラーが発生しました。エラー文で検索してみたら、[AttributeError: module 'pycodestyle' has no attribute 'break_around_binary_operator'](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues/427) このページがヒットし、google翻訳にかけてみたら、pycodestyleのバージョンがflake8のバージョンと互換性がないと翻訳されました。この翻訳が正しければ、pycodestyleをダウングレードしてエラーでなくなるまで試せばよいということですか？

Comment: `flake8` と入力するだけでも上記のエラーが出ました。原因がいまいちわからないのですが、pythonやpipのバージョンが低いからこのようなエラーが出るんでしょうか？pipのバージョンは18.0です

Comment: 可能性4を試してみたら無事に機能するようになりました。確かにpycodestyleのバージョンが新しすぎて、flake8が動かなかったみたいです。ありがとうございました。